# google script - how to overcome fact, that it is not possible to use built in function in custom function

Tags: javascript

at the starting point  - I am completely new to programming, so maybe my question is silly.

Please could you give me some advice with this problem?

```
function GETCOUNTFROMTITLE(title) {
  var re = new Regexp ("^[0-9]+.[cC]ount");
  if (re.test(title) ){
    return "yes";
  }
}
```

In custom function, I need to process regular expression evaluation a then do some more operation with given string, but I am getting error message 
    "ReferenceError: undefined „Regexp“. (row 2, file „code“)".
How can I make this work?

Thank you very much
any advice will help

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case-sensitive.

You mean `RegExp`.

Also, you should use a regex literal instead.

And, you should return a boolean.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Now I don't have an error message anymore, but the function returns nothing. And what exactly mean literal ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions